# Can Mechanize make Javascript calls?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, mechanize

Can Mechanize make Javascript calls?

This would be handy to negotiate AJAX when screen-scraping...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can't. If you need to interact with javascript, you should look at other solutions like [watir](http://watir.com/).

Comment: Hmmm, Watir is nice, but creates a few more problems for me.